# spring batch 2.2.7 app throwing "Invalid column name". Very simple working Code bombs

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-batch

I have a spring batch 2.2.7 app that worked fine all this time but today started throwing "Invalid Column".

I ran the below SQL in DataGrip just to be sure and it's working just fine.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM Equipment WHERE rowNum < 
 10 ORDER BY id ASC) WHERE ROWNUM <= 10
```

The code :

```
factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
factoryBean.setSelectClause("select *");
factoryBean.setFromClause("from EQUIPMENT");
factoryBean.setSortKey("ID");
factoryBean.setWhereClause("where rowNum < 10");
```

The SQL didn't change, the DB schema didn't change, the code didn't change. It worked 12 hours ago but doesn't any longer. What gives ?.

I tried to pursue this further myself by restarting the application after setting the property
logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.core=TRACE

This resulted in the following output log.

```
2020-06-05 15:37:37.162 DEBUG 17276 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing SQL query [SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM Equipment WHERE rowNum < 10 ORDER BY id ASC) WHERE ROWNUM <= 10]
2020-06-05 15:37:37.715 ERROR 17276 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Encountered an error executing step xxxxxxxxxx in job yyyyyyyyyyy

org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM Equipment WHERE rowNum < 10 ORDER BY id ASC) WHERE ROWNUM <= 10]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name
  at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:235) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1443) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:388) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:452) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:462) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcPagingItemReader.doReadPage(JdbcPagingItemReader.java:210) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to  http://shanhe.me/2011/05/15/read-carefully-spring-jdbctemplate-bad-sql-grammar-exception, I was able to fix this.

Nothing wrong with the SQL Grammar.

I discovered that I made a very small change to table schema. I renamed a column. The RowMapper that I used to map the Equipment Table still used the old column name and hence the problem.

Suggestion to Spring jdbc team : When you throw ...jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException, can you suggest to the user that their Mapping of the column could probably be wrong. Since you're not putting any trace logging about this error, atleast when you discover, you can suggest that there could be a mapping error. Looks like I'm not the only one who's hit this issue.